# changing extension to .mm can't find the header anymore

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

I am working on a Iphone Application. I need to use C++ code inside `MainViewController` class. For that I renamed the `MainViewController.m` to `MainViewController.mm` in order to accept C++ code.

However after doing that it looks like it lost the link with the `MainViewController.h` file. I can no longer synthesize properties declared in the .h file and can no longer create action in the header file. It can't find the .mm file. and if I try to "Jump to definition" it says `Symbol not found`

How can I fix that. Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Close and reopen the Xcode project**

if that fails, **Build and remove any errors** which may have been introduced as a result of changing the type to compile as.

if that fails, **Clean All** and rebuild.

if that fails, got to the Organizer, choose "Projects" >  *YOUR_PROJECT* and **Delete its Derived Data**.

Comment: I had to do a manual clean from the organizer. For some reason the Xcode clean project doesn't work. I will accept your answer but please add this info to your answer in case someone has the same problem. Thanks